# Написать на Java API соеденение по примеру PHP

Tags: php, java, api

хочу по апи на java получить .csv файл для дальнейшей обработки, пример есть только на PHP, несколько дней уже пробую по разному и никак не могу получить в ответ этот файл, насколько понимаю, я не правильно отправляю туда запрос, вернее не в том формате шифровки в котором требуется. Знаний у меня мало, опыта тем более, укажите плиз направление в котором копать?

Описание к примеру --
При формировании контрольной подписи значения полей "склеиваются" в одну строку с разделителем "+" в следующем порядке:

```
anonymous
dtmfUserAnswer
firstTime
from
fromNumber
names
numbersInvolved
numbersRinged
outgoingLine
state
to
toAnswer
toNumber
tree
showTreeId
type
user
секретный ключ.
```

От полученной строки вычисляется MD5.

Пример на PHP

```
    $user = '081121';
    $from = date('d.m.Y');
    $to = date('d.m.Y');
    $type = '0';
    $state = '0';
    $tree = '';
    $showTreeId = '1';
    $fromNumber = '';
    $numbersRinged = 0;
    $numbersInvolved = 0;
    $names = 0;
    $outgoingLine = 1;
    $toNumber = '';
    $toAnswer = '';
    $anonymous = '1';
    $firstTime = '0';
    $dtmfUserAnswer = 0;
    $secret = 'ваш ключ интеграции';
    
    $hashString = join('+', array($anonymous, $dtmfUserAnswer, $firstTime, $from, $fromNumber, $names, $numbersInvolved, $numbersRinged, $outgoingLine, $showTreeId, $state, $to, $toAnswer, $toNumber, $tree, $type, $user, $secret));
    $hash = md5($hashString);
    
    $url = 'https://someurl.com/api/statistic/export';
    $query = http_build_query(array(
        'anonymous' => $anonymous,
        'firstTime' => $firstTime,
        'from' => $from,
        'fromNumber' => $fromNumber,
        'numbersRinged' => $numbersRinged
        'outgoingLine' => $outgoingLine,
        'showTreeId' => $showTreeId,
        'state' => $state,
        'to' => $to,
        'toAnswer' => $toAnswer,
        'toNumber' => $toNumber,
        'tree' => $tree,
        'type' => $type,
        'user' => $user,
        'dtmfUserAnswer' => $dtmfUserAnswer,
        'hash' => $hash,
    ));
    
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=stat_$from-$to.csv");
    echo $output;
```

Мой код если нужно но он так и не работает)

```
String urlAdress = "https://someurl.com/api/statistic/export";
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection;
    OutputStream os = null;
    InputStreamReader isR = null;
    BufferedReader bfR = null;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    try{
        Map<String,String> postargs = new HashMap<>();
        postargs.put("anonymous", "1");
        postargs.put("firstTime", "0");
        postargs.put("from", "27.04.2022");
        postargs.put("fromNumber", "");
        postargs.put("state", "0");
        postargs.put("to", "27.04.2022");
        postargs.put("toAnswer", "");
        postargs.put("toNumber", "");
        postargs.put("tree", "");
        postargs.put("type", "0");
        postargs.put("user", "081121");
        postargs.put("secret", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

        byte[] out = postargs.toString().getBytes();

        url = new URL(urlAdress);
        httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
        httpURLConnection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
        httpURLConnection.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(200);
        httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(200);
        httpURLConnection.connect();


        try {
            os = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            os.write(out);
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.err.print(e.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println(httpURLConnection.getResponseCode());
        if (HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK == httpURLConnection.getResponseCode()){
            isR = new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());
            bfR = new BufferedReader(isR);
            String line;
            while ((line=bfR.readLine()) != null){
                stringBuilder.append(line);
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(isR);
    }catch (MalformedURLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (IOException e){
        System.err.print(e.getMessage());
    }finally {
        try{
            isR.close();
        }catch (IOException e){
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try{
            bfR.close();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try{
            os.close();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Он не работает так как вы не вычисляете хэш, и не добавляете его к параметрам. Где код для его  вычисления?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это все очень далеко от того, что делает PHP

Для того, чтобы отправить http запрос, лучше использовать что-то более высокоуровневое, к примеру, я взял okhttp, подключайте зависимость:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp/4.9.3

Поскольку я не знаю секретного ключа, то пртестировать это не могу, однако, примерно это будет выглядеть так (дальше разбирайтесь и дебажте):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
import okhttp3.FormBody;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
        Map<String, String> postargs = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        postargs.put("anonymous", "1");
        postargs.put("dtmfUserAnswer", "0");
        postargs.put("firstTime", "0");
        postargs.put("from", "27.04.2022");
        postargs.put("fromNumber", "");
        postargs.put("names", "0");
        postargs.put("numbersInvolved", "0");
        postargs.put("numbersRinged", "0");
        postargs.put("outgoingLine", "1");
        postargs.put("showTreeId", "1");
        postargs.put("state", "0");
        postargs.put("to", "27.04.2022");
        postargs.put("toAnswer", "");
        postargs.put("toNumber", "");
        postargs.put("tree", "");
        postargs.put("type", "0");
        postargs.put("user", "081121");

        String secret = "secret";

        String urlAdress = "https://someurl.com/api/statistic/export";

        Map<String, String> postargsWithMd5 = addMd5(secret, postargs);

        String content = send(urlAdress, postargsWithMd5);

        System.out.println(content);

    }

    private static Map<String, String> addMd5(String secret, Map<String, String> postargs) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : postargs.entrySet()) sb.append(entry.getValue()).append("+");
        String hashString = sb.append(secret).toString();
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        md.update(hashString.getBytes());
        postargs.put("hash", DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(md.digest()));
        return postargs;
    }
    
    private static String send(String url, Map<String, String> postargs) throws IOException {
        FormBody.Builder bodyBuilder = new FormBody.Builder();
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : postargs.entrySet()) bodyBuilder.add(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .addHeader("Content-Disposition", String.join("", "attachment; filename=stat_", postargs.get("from"), "-" + postargs.get("to"), ".csv"))
                .url(url)
                .post(bodyBuilder.build())
                .build();
        Response response = new OkHttpClient().newCall(request).execute();
        return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.body().byteStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
                .lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
    }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо, ваш пример запускается отлично, но вывод данных  идёт обычной страницы среди которого нашел такой блок.
`<div id="circle-grid" class="wrapper layout">
            <h2>Произошла ошибка</h2>
    Неправильный хеш
    </div>`
буду искать дальше в этом направлении, благодарю за помощь

Comment: @Анатолий проверяйте последовательность полей, которые вы помещаете в map, она не может меняться и четко определена в условии задания. кроме того, я не уверен , корректно ли иметь пустые значения вроде этого postargs.put("fromNumber", ""), потому как в этом случае мы имеем строку для расчета хеша с фрагментом вида ...fromNumber++... итого мы получаем два знака плюс подряд. что делать в этом случае я не знаю, потому как это определяется конкретной апихой, но это, разумется, влияет на хеш.

Comment: меня попросили отправить строку запроса который мы отправляем к ним на сайт чтобы понять почему хеш не проходит, я уже всё что можно там пробовал вывести на экран, но нигде не нашел, итоговый запрос типа в формате  url&параметры&hash
не подскажешь как мне её узнать?

Comment: @Анатолий помочь преобразовать пост запрос в строку, включая тело запроса, не может никто)) урла с параметрами здесь не существует, это немного другой запрос. а вот хеш считается из строки, которая хранится в перемнной hashString метода addMd5(). скорее всего именно эту строку просят. выводим в консоль, отправляем...

Comment: @Анатолий в общем , если до сих пор не нашли проблему, то все довольно просто: код php не включает в хеш ключи. кроме того, у вас в map не содержатся все ключи, которые соджержатся в примере php. с учетом того, что php приведены ключи, которым соответствует пустое значение, могу предположить, что указывать нужно все (обязательно в аналогичном порядке!). пробуйте этот код, сейчас хеш совпадает (ответ исправил)

Comment: Да. благодарю, я сидел всё это время перебирал разные варианты и оказалось что вместо .touppercase на хеш коде должно было быть .tolowercase
Также пришел к выводу что ключи не надо было ложить в хеш, а только значения в том порядке что нужно, включая пустые чтобы вышел такой формат 1++0+27.04.2022+225++++++0+27.04.2022+225
уже по крайней мере выдаёт какой никакой результат, еще разберусь как мне принять .csv оттуда)) и тогда уже здесь отпишусь что всё решено))

Comment: спасибо за вашу проделанную работу, премного благодарен, за эти дни оч много вычитал))

Answer (score 0):

Для отправка http запрос, вы можете использовать мою библиотеку.
Итак, охраняйте это код как отдельный класс

```
public class HttpPutData extends Thread {
private final String url;
private final String method;
String result_data = "Empty";
final String[] data;
final String[] field;

// Initialize the spannable string builders.
final SpannableStringBuilder requestHeadersBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder();

public HttpPutData(String url, String method, String[] field, String[] data) {
    this.url = url;
    this.method = method;
    this.data = new String[data.length];
    this.field = new String[field.length];
    System.arraycopy(field, 0, this.field, 0, field.length);
    System.arraycopy(data, 0, this.data, 0, data.length);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        String UTF8 = "UTF-8", iso = "iso-8859-1";
        URL url = new URL(this.url);
        HttpURLConnection httpUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpUrlConnection.setRequestMethod(this.method);
        httpUrlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        httpUrlConnection.setDoInput(true);

        String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android;") AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Mobile Safari/537.36";
        // Set the `User-Agent` header property.
        httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", userAgent);

        // Add the `User-Agent` header to the string builder and format the text.
        requestHeadersBuilder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        requestHeadersBuilder.append("User-Agent", new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        requestHeadersBuilder.append(":  ");
        requestHeadersBuilder.append(userAgent);

        // send Accept-Language
        String localeString = Locale.getDefault().toString();
        // Set the `Accept-Language` header property.
        httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", localeString);

        // Add the `Accept-Language` header to the string builder and format the text.
        requestHeadersBuilder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        requestHeadersBuilder.append("Accept-Language", new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        requestHeadersBuilder.append(":  ");
        requestHeadersBuilder.append(localeString);

        // Get the cookies for the current domain.
        String cookiesString = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url.toString());
        // Only process the cookies if they are not null.
        if (cookiesString != null) {
            // Add the cookies to the header property.
            httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookiesString);

            // Add the cookie header to the string builder and format the text.
            requestHeadersBuilder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            requestHeadersBuilder.append("Cookie", new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            requestHeadersBuilder.append(":  ");
            requestHeadersBuilder.append(cookiesString);
        }

        OutputStream outputStream = httpUrlConnection.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, UTF8));
        StringBuilder post_data = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < this.field.length; i++) {
            post_data.append(URLEncoder.encode(this.field[i], "UTF-8")).append("=").append(URLEncoder.encode(this.data[i], UTF8)).append("&");
        }
        bufferedWriter.write(post_data.toString());
        bufferedWriter.flush();
        bufferedWriter.close();
        outputStream.close();
        InputStream inputStream = httpUrlConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, iso));
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        String result_line;
        while ((result_line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(result_line);
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
        inputStream.close();
        httpUrlConnection.disconnect();
        setData(result.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        setData(e.toString());
    }
}

public boolean startPut() {
    HttpPutData.this.start();
    return true;
}

public boolean onComplete() {
    while (true) {
        if (!this.isAlive()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}

public String getResult() {
    return this.getData();
}

public void setData(String result_data) {
    this.result_data = result_data;
}

public String getData() {
    return result_data;
}
```

}

затем на ваш Activity или Fragment вызовите это код

```
    Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.post(() -> {

        // count and key
        String[] field = new String[2]; // list with key
        field[0] = "key1"; //index and key
        field[1] = "key2"; //index and key

        //Creating array for data
        String[] data = new String[2]; // list with data
        data[0] = "value1"; // index and value
        data[1] = "value2"; // index and value

        HttpPutData httpPutData = new HttpPutData("http://url.com/main.php", "POST", field, data); // link, method, arrayKey, arrayValue;

        if (httpPutData.startPut()) {
            if (httpPutData.onComplete()) {
                String result = httpPutData.getResult();
                if(result != null){
                  Log.i("HttpPutData", result);
                }
            }
        }
    }); // end handler
```

не забудьте добавить разрешения на использование интернета в **manifest**!

весь данные будет отправлено в виде массива, на страница main.php где вы можете легко обрабатывать с помощью php.